# I have draw surface using triangles (Android-Studio opengl es 1) how to load one texture on this surface

Tags: opengl-es

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWPq4.png)

the source :
public class GLsufaceT {
    private FloatBuffer vertBuff ,texBuffer;enter code here
    private ShortBuffer pBuff;

```
private float [] vertices ={ //Coordinates
         -4,-2,0  
        ,-3,-2,0
        ,-2,-3,0
        ,-1,-3,0
        ,0,-3,0
        ,1,-3,0
        ,2,-3,0
        ,3,-3,0
        ,4,-3,0
        ,-4,-2,0
        ,-3,-2,0
        ,-2,-2,0
        ,-1,-2,0
        ,0,-2,0
        ,1,-2,0
        ,2,-2,0
        ,3,-2,0
        ,4,-2,0
        ,-4,-1,0
        ,-3,-1,0
        ,-2,-1,0
        ,-1,-1,0
        ,0,-1,0
        ,1,-1,0
        ,2,-1,0
        ,3,-1,0
        ,4,-1,0
        ,-4, 0,0
        ,-3, 0,0
        ,-2, 0,0
        ,-1, 0,0
        ,0, 0,0
        ,1, 0,0
        ,2, 0,0
        ,3, 0,0
        ,4, 0,0
        ,-4, 1,0
        ,-3, 1,0
        ,-2, 1,0
        ,-1, 1,0
        ,0, 1,0
        ,1, 1,0
        ,2, 1,0
        ,3, 1,0
        ,4, 1,0
        ,-4, 2,0
        ,-3, 2,0
        ,-2, 2,0
        ,-1, 2,0
        ,0, 2,0
        ,1, 2,0
        ,2, 2,0
        ,3, 2,0
        ,4, 2,0
        ,-4, 3,0
        ,-3, 3,0
        ,-2, 3,0
        ,-1, 3,0
        ,0, 3,0
        ,1, 3,0
        ,2, 3,0
        ,3, 3,0
        ,4, 3,0



};
float[] texCoords = {

        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1f,  0.0f,
        0.0f, 1f,
        1f,  1f,
};
```

private short[] pindex={ 0,1,9             //Triangles 
                            ,1,9,10
                             ,1,2,10
                             ,2,10,11
                             ,2,3,11
                             ,3,11,12
                             ,3,4,12
                             ,4,12,13
                             ,4,5,13
                             ,5,13,14
                             ,5,6,14
                             ,6,14,15
                             ,6,7,15
                             ,7,15,16
                             ,7,8,16
                             ,8,16,17
                             ,9,10,18
                             ,10,18,19
                             ,10,11,19
                             ,11,19,20
                             ,11,12,20
                             ,12,20,21
                             ,12,13,21
                             ,13,21,22
                             ,13,14,22
                             ,14,22,23
                             ,14,15,23
                             ,15,23,24
                             ,15,16,24
                             ,16,24,25
                             ,16,17,25
                             ,17,25,26
                             ,18,19,27
                             ,19,27,28
                             ,19,20,28
                             ,20,28,29
                             ,20,21,29
                             ,21,29,30
                             ,21,22,30
                             ,22,30,31
                             ,22,23,31
                             ,23,31,32
                             ,23,24,32
                             ,24,32,33
                             ,24,25,33
                             ,25,33,34
                             ,25,26,34
                             ,26,34,35
                             ,27,28,36
                             ,28,36,37
                             ,28,29,37
                             ,29,37,38
                             ,29,30,38
                             ,30,38,39
                             ,30,31,39
                             ,31,39,40
                             ,31,32,40
                             ,32,40,41
                             ,32,33,41
                             ,33,41,42
                             ,33,34,42
                             ,34,42,43
                             ,34,35,43
                             ,35,43,44
                             ,36,37,45
                             ,37,45,46
                             ,37,38,46
                             ,38,46,47
                             ,38,39,47
                             ,39,47,48
                             ,39,40,48
                             ,40,48,49
                             ,40,41,49
                             ,41,49,50
                             ,41,42,50
                             ,42,50,51
                             ,42,43,51
                             ,43,51,52
                             ,43,44,52
                             ,44,52,53
                             ,45,46,54
                             ,46,54,55
                             ,46,47,55
                             ,47,55,56
                             ,47,48,56
                             ,48,56,57
                             ,48,49,57
                             ,49,57,58
                             ,49,50,58
                             ,50,58,59
                             ,50,51,59
                             ,51,59,60
                             ,51,52,60
                             ,52,60,61
                             ,52,53,61
                             ,53,61,62 };*/
    int[] textureIDs = new int[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWPq4.png); // Array for 1 texture-ID (NEW)

```
public GLsufaceT() {
    ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
    vertBuff.put(vertices);
    vertBuff.position(0);
    ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pindex.length * 2);
    pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    pBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
    pBuff.put(pindex);
    pBuff.position(0);
    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
    texBuffer.put(texCoords);
    texBuffer.position(0);

}
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuff);
   gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, pindex.length,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_FRONT);
}

public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]); // Bind to texture ID


    // Set up texture filters
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // Construct an input stream to texture image
    InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.jay);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        // Read and decode input as bitmap
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
    } finally {
        try {
            istream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture ID
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

}

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want it like this for example [link](http://imgur.com/WuY0nan)
project one picture on the full surface